# Connect function not accessible on requiring mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7]
On requiring mongoose (4.3.6),

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/urlshortner');
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function

Comment: You don't happen to have a file called `mongoose.js` (or `mongoose/index.js`) in your local directory?

Comment: did you install it with: `npm install mongoose`?

Comment: I was trying to connect to mongo db on the client side. Discovered that it has to be done on the server side. Now it is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

var mongoose = require('mongoose').Mongoose;